# How to calculate the dimensions of the 3D object from MeshAnchor.Geometry?

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit, realitykit, visionos

From the Apple visionOS ARKit scene reconstruction, we can get the geometry of the 3D objects: MeshAnchor.Geometry.
I have tried calculating the bounding box of it but had no success.

How could we calculate the width, heigh and depth from the MeshAnchor.Geometry?